# Could I use the gender-neutral “their” for the antecedent “account”?

Tags: pronouns

I’ve come across this sentence and found the pronoun-antecedent reference quite confusing:

> I am led to believe that account is not genuine about their country of origin.

Is this a common or acceptable usage in the technology age?

I understand the concept of using the gender-neutral they/them/their for a singular individual, but I would not have considered “account” to be an individual. Does the fact that an account can (in these times be considered to) have agency warrant the use of the personal singular pronouns his/her/their, or should an account be referred to as “it”?

There was no other antecedent the author could have been referring to, and in many cases an account may be more than one person, so account holder or user doesn’t always work.

Background information:

Merriam Webster offers this definition: 3a(1) : a formal business arrangement providing for regular dealings or services (such as banking, advertising, or store credit) and involving the establishment and maintenance of an account
a checking account
also : CLIENT, CUSTOMER
They are one of our most important accounts.

Comment: The antecedent for *their* is in a preceding sentence somewhere. For example: _**They** told us where they came from. I am led to believe [that] that account is not genuine about **their** country of origin._

Comment: Quite apart from the fact that many/most native speakers wouldn't accept this use of the noun ***account*** (to mean the account *holder*), I don't think the usage ***is not genuine*** is a suitable alternative to ***lied***. So I suggest OP's text should be changed to *I am led to believe that account **holder lied** about their country of origin* (or ***gave inaccurate information***, if ***lied*** seems a bit strong for the context).

Comment: This further demonstates the point that the speaker is attributing agency to the account; they avoided “account holder” and “lied” because the agent is the account, which may have more than one holder, and doesn’t “lie” the way a person does

Comment: The fundamental problem, as I think FF observes, is with 'the account is not genuine about'. A sentient referent 'he/she is // they are not [being] genuine about ...' is idiomatic. ////'[T]heir' can only acceptably be used to refer to plural referents, or singular human referents of as yet unrevealed gender. Not animals or inanimate referents (even allowing for personification).

Comment: This appears to be an attempt to shoehorn 'genuine' (and perhaps 'account') into [an] unnatural place/s in a sentence. 'They did not give a/n ADJ account of their early life' is natural with 'truthful' or 'accurate'; 'genuine' is somewhat less idiomatic. 'We have a genuine account of ...' means that the account is accurately recorded, whether factually true or not.

Comment: The problem that the question is about exists only in so far as one insists on using *account* in a jargonistic way; if one steps outside the jargon, the problem will disappear.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 1. I don't think that's the sense of "account" invoked in the sentence at issue. I think OP is pretty clear that "account" in that sentence refers to a user account, like your ELU account. 2. As for the usage you are discussing here, I don't know why you said "a genuine account of" is "_less idiomatic_". A preliminary search on Google Books seems to suggest it is a pretty common collocation. Attestations from notable authors, including George Washington and Leslie Stephen, can be found.

Answer (score 3):

Actually yes.  As strange as it may sound, "account" refers to a person, in this instance.  If you use Twitter, for instance, you will frequently see users use the word "account" as a synonym for "user."  To convince myself of this, I searched for the phrase "one of the worst accounts," which was the first phrase I tried that sifted out other meanings of "account" ("this account is," for instance, turns up mostly remarks about newspaper stories).  Here are some examples I found (no offense to the users in question; I do not know who any of these people are and have no opinion about their Twitter presences):

> Mark Jackson Burner is the WORST burner account on here and is genuinely one of the worst accounts on Twitter dude. He is just really unfunny I can’t remember ever laughing at a tweet of his
>
> https://twitter.com/Schnuzel/status/1419749671908544512

> I can’t believe some of my mutuals follow this MF. This Easter Island looking ass dude is one of the worst accounts on here. Know he’s a Grade A weirdo.
>
> https://twitter.com/PersnicketyK/status/1437426989841985545

> Just want to add to this excellent thread that Rex Chapman is one of the worst accounts on this platform and RT-ing him is the kind of thing you may be asked about at the doors to the afterlife.
>
> https://twitter.com/BDSixsmith/status/1419364909763244040

I found some more with "this account uses."  Still everyone's pretty negative, but again, not familiar with the people being criticized:

> Not really. The way this account uses it it's, "Get mad at what we post unless it turns out to be fake, in which case it's satire."
>
> https://twitter.com/nate_e_u/status/1465063962307923974

> @twittersupport  this account uses your service to [harass] underage women and men [with] their photos, doxxing and threatening them
>
> https://twitter.com/Hmmmmrestricted/status/1465025227306545165

If we accept that "account" has the meaning of "user," then clearly it may be used with possessive pronouns too -- "some accounts constantly insult their own followers," for instance, would logically be a sentence that I might write with this meaning.

If I might speculate on how this usage came to be, it's normal on Twitter for there to be accounts which are operated by more than one person.  It would seem strange to refer to the Nestle Twitter account as a "user."  But most Twitter accounts *are* just an individual user, so once people started writing things about what they thought about "accounts," or what "accounts" say or do, it was a natural next step to start applying that language to individual-user accounts and conflating the person and the account.

Comment: Merriam-Webster and Lexico have similar [definitions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account) of "account" as "an arrangement in which a person uses the Internet or email services of a particular company". But you're right, I don't think "arrangement" is quite the right word any more - an account in this sense means an identity on a particular Internet service, closer to a persona or avatar than an arrangement for access like paying someone to watch cable TV.

Answer (score 0):

No, using "their" would be implying that the account is a being, like a person. For inanimate or abstract things, one would avoid using personal pronouns. The word "its" is the appropriate word here.

Comment: Unless you can be certain of the context of the sentence, your assumption that "their" refers to "that account" is likely to be incorrect. Most native speakers would assume that the author of the sentence, in deliberately choosing "their" rather than "its", is necessarily referring to the country of origin of *the person who gave the account*.

Comment: There was no previous antecedent； the author clearly thought of the account as having agency, so I was wondering if others agreed with this usage

Comment: @LisaP - Are you sure this is about a business account and not a retelling of an occurrence as from a witness?

Comment: It wasn’t a business account at all and was used to mean “user” (site similar to this); I provided the MW definition to show the similarity. It is a case of the author prescribing agency to a digital entity

Comment: @LisaP In the original sentence, most native speakers would interpret "that account" as a metonym for both the account, and the user of that account (or users, though it's often just a single user). Unless you're suggesting that the account is some sort of bot or AI that runs without any human intervention. I would interpret that sentence as "The person [or people] running the account is [are] giving misleading answers about their country of origin when asked."

Comment: Most native speakers would **not** interpret 'account' to stand for the holder of the account; such usage of the word is confined to a certain business jargon which is spoken by only a minority of the speakers of the language.

Comment: Is it possible that in addition to being business jargon as jsw mentioned, it's also used by Gen Z for online accounts to stand in for "user"? Maybe I should mention that I'm a native speaker.

Comment: I think this is a pretty clear case where "most English speakers'" intuitions are going to depend on how old they are.