# If the customer often updates * their * file? gender-neutral pronoun for client/customer

Tags: pronouns, business-language, gender-neutral

This is a bit like [Could I use the gender-neutral “their” for the antecedent “account”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577709/could-i-use-the-gender-neutral-their-for-the-antecedent-account)

In business language, should you use singular or plural pronouns for a client or customer that stands for a company?

Could or should you say something like:

> "If the customer often updates their file"

Or should you take "her" instead of "their", which I saw in times?

Comment: Let's not insult the customer, or the reader. There are workarounds like "If the customer often makes updates."

Comment: *Their* seems to have been the path of least resistance for the past 20 years or so. Personally, I switched in 1981, when I was writing government contracts, and have not seen a reason to revert.

Comment: Yes - let's not insult the customer!

Comment: If you've got some sort of philosophical objection to singular their, "If customers often update their files". Note there are several questions about singular there already on this site.

Comment: Yawn. With ***367*** upvotes as I write, does this answer your question? [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-vs-her-vs-their)